# Integrating OpenCV in an Android project: Android only supports versionless libraries ending with the .so suffix

Tags: android, opencv, cmake

I have just built OpenCV from source and adjusted my CMake configuration as so:

```
set(OpenCV_DIR "/home/ivelin/opencv/release")
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

target_link_libraries(${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Generating Android Package
  Input file: /home/ivelin/Desktop/SecureMe/smart-client/android-secureme-deployment-settings.json
  Output directory: /home/ivelin/Desktop/SecureMe/smart-client/android-build/
  Application binary: secureme
  Android build platform: android-34
  Install to device: No
The bundled library lib/libopencv_core.so.409 doesn't end with .so. Android only supports versionless libraries ending with the .so suffix.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/secureme_make_apk.dir/build.make:71: CMakeFiles/secureme_make_apk] Error 12
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:121: CMakeFiles/secureme_make_apk.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

It is interesting why is that because I have a file libpopencv_core.so and it has a symbolic link to libopencv_core.so.409 and not the other way around, so I am confused why I get such error.

[image]

What causes this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: [crosspost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266159): https://forum.opencv.org/t/integrating-opencv-in-an-android-project/16689

Comment: Yes, sorry ? I didn’t know that was a problem. I thought they are just separated platforms and I could ask separately on any